# Angular 5 save damaged excel file from Spring Boot

Tags: excel, angular, spring-boot, xlsx, filesaver.js

I'm really stucked here. I've read many posts about this issue and nothing works for this example. I tried with different contentType as Blob, bufferArray... with no result.

I have this simple Spring Boot controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/square/export-excel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exportExcel(@RequestBody List<SquaredEmissions> dto, HttpServletResponse response) {

  try {
    Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
    byte[] output = excelHelper.exportExcel(book);
    filesHelper.serveXlsxBrowser(response, output, "excel.xlsx");

  } catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
```

and the helpers code:

```
public byte[] exportExcel(Workbook book) throws IOException {

  if (book == null) {
    return new byte[0];
  }

  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  book.write(output);
  output.close();

  return output.toByteArray();
}

public void serveXlsxBrowser(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] file, String fileName)
    throws IOException {

  response.setContentType(
    "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8");
  response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
  response.getOutputStream().write(file);
  response.getOutputStream().flush(); 
}
```

Then in my Angular service I'm doing the following call

```
export () {

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=UTF-8');

this.http
  .post(this.PATHS.export, this.squareService.getEmissions(), { headers: headers } )
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.fileService.saveExcelToFileSystem(response);
  });  }


saveExcelToFileSystem (response) {

const contentDispositionHeader: string = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
const blob = new Blob([response._body], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; ; charset=UTF-8' });

if (contentDispositionHeader != null) {
  const parts: string[] = contentDispositionHeader.split(';');
  let filename = parts[1].split('=')[1];
  filename = filename.substring(1, filename.length - 1);

  saveAs(blob, filename);

} else {
  saveAs(blob);
}
```

}

After that, I get to download a excel file (.xlsx) but the file is corrupted and unreadeable.
The _body of the response looks like
PK��:M_rels/.rels���J1���Pr���
"�u/"�Md}��ff�L��F���E]w@�c���?H��9L�r�
��E�������nu�F�G2v7�g��P�N|*�Bb10��k��(`i8Q���s@�e�uB;bOzӶ�:e�1U흁�wkP�=��yү��'汩�:xK��X�:o��s�('ҏ^�^��|�8����.���:4EGn�je�T��.N8Y��7����@�?�?����P;�PK�A���UPK��:M[Content_Types].xml���N�0��H�C�+�]8 �=�s�J�X�Mc����}{6i��PT��X3��x�܍W�UK���ЈK9�
�F�O��Q�`�ŀ�Q�����넥

And I can't get to know why.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Angular have nothing to do with this issue. Although I'm not sure if this is correct but at least **it works**.

In my example I was trying to export an empty Excel file

```
new XSSFWorkbook();
```

now I'm adding some dummy value to the first cell in that Excel file and the export is working fine.

```
Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = book.createSheet();
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
row.createCell(0).setCellValue("hello");
```

This way no matter about Content-type is defined correctly or excel version is .xls or .xlsx.

Now my doubt is about Apache POI library, perhaps writing some content is mandatory for exporting correctly.